# Deploying unsafe code in Azure cloud

Tags: .net, azure, unsafe

Has anyone tried deploying unsafe code in Azure?  I'm working with code containing unsafe blocks dealing with pointers and all that fun stuff.  And I'm wondering if that has something to do with errors I'm getting trying to deploy/upgrade the web project in Azure.

Also, is there actually a way to view specific errors that are breaking the upgrade?

Fyi, yes I do have 'allow unsafe code' checked in my web project settings.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

This is the error I get trying to upgrade...

> Role instances recycled for a certain
>   amount of times during an update or
>   upgrade operation. This indicates that
>   the new version of your service or the
>   configuration settings you provided
>   when configuring the service prevent
>   role instances from running. The most
>   likely reason for this is that your
>   code throws an unhandled exception.
>   Please consider fixing your service or
>   changing your configuration settings
>   so that role instances do not throw
>   unhandled exceptions. Then start
>   another update or upgrade operation.
>   Until you start another update or
>   upgrade operation, Windows Azure will
>   continue trying to update your service
>   to the new version or configuration
>   you provided

Comment: It's pretty generic - I've updated the question with it.  Btw, I did run this locally in the Azure simulation environment, and there are no issues building or running the app.

Comment: Add `catch` blocks and see if you get errors.

Comment: Where?  I mean this is happening at deployment/upgrade time.  And where would I check for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of folks run 'unsafe' code in various forms (mostly native C/C++).  If the role is recycling, you have an unhandled exception that may or may not be related to the unsafe code.  I would suggest several things:

1) Try running the code local in the DevFabric

2) Check your On_Start block.  Surprisingly often this is where the problem is (e.g. bad path, bad config, etc.)

3) Enable the diagnostics logging and see if you can get any trace info.

Comment: I guess that's the best we got. :)